# How to create QLables along with QlineEdit dynamically in dialog window using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am developing a plugin which allows the user to edit the features attribute information. I have a combo box from which user can select the layer name for which attributes are to be edited. I need to add field names of layer selected in combo box as labels along with empty line edit boxes. How this can be done?

```
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    fields = selectedLayer.pendingFields()
    fieldnames = [field.name() for field in fields]
```

Something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know there is need to create such thing, cuz it already exists.

As far as I understand you want this:

```
iface.getFeatureForm(layer, feature)
```

[Here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a0634b6e8b1bcc6cbcd6cb9460562ff4e) you have more info about it.